# Is there any Google Analytic Streaming/Real-time API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking for a streaming/real-time API for Google Analytic any source of reference or documentation ?

Answer (score 3):

It is. Now Google has launched new Real Time API for Google Analytics. This API is very similar to Google Analytics API. Which extracts the Google Analytics real time data in the given [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/)

To start development on this API, you can get API parameters from [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide)

Comment: @sudhanshu it would be great if you could accept the answer if it solved your question, so other people can easily find it too.